# LuaLaTeX and counters

Tags: luatex, counters

I'm trying to use values from expanded macros within a direct lua block, but I can't figure out how to get a value from any macro that has braces in it.

```
\directlua { tex.print(\value{footnote}} }
```

Never works the way i expect it, All i want it to do is for it to print out the current value of the counter footnote. Do I need to escape the braces?

A minimal example that doesnt work:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\footnote{hello}
\directlua { tex.enableprimitives('',tex.extraprimitives()) }
\catcode `\{=1
\catcode `\}=2
\directlua { here = here or {}; here.foo = 5 }
\directlua { here = here or {}; tex.print(here.foo + 5) }
\directlua { tex.print(\value{footnote}} }
\end{document}
```

And the errors;

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
! LuaTeX error <\directlua >:1: unexpected symbol near '\'.
l.13 \directlua { tex.print(\value{footnote}}
                                              }
?
```

\

Answer (score 3):

```
\directlua { tex.print(\value{footnote}} }
```

there is a missing closing parenthesis ). However you can write:

```
\directlua { tex.print(\thefootnote)}
```

at least for numeric footnotes

Comment: Thanks Herbert. I still have the problem of the braces causing compile errors with any macro that has braces, how can i fix this?

Comment: The line is fixed, i put the parenthesis where it belong, still same problem.

Comment: @Brendan: did you tried it with `(\thefootnote)`

Comment: it's "you must", not "you can", as `\value{footnote}` gives the unexpandable token `\c@footnote`; so `\thefootnote` or `\arabic{footnote}`.

Answer (score 2):

In ConTeXt, counters created by `\definenumber` or `\definestructurecounter` are accessible at the lua side using `structure.counters.data` table. That way, you do not have to do any conversions at the TeX level. You can use helper functions like `structure.counteres.value` to get the value of a counter. I don't know if any LaTeX package provides similar functionality for LaTeX counters.

Comment: Thanks Aditya, I would like the LuaLaTeX method of doing something similar to what you posted.